# Calling an onclick in a img?

Tags: javascript, css

I have several thumb nails that I want to click on and have a larger version pop up over the thumbnails. I have the code that I was using and it works if I set it up in  tags as a link but I cannot seem to make the thumbanail img itself clicable

HTML, Link that works

```
 <li><a href="#" onclick="toggle('widget1')">Toggle</a></li>
```

javaScript

```
function toggle(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);

  if (e.style.display == '')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = '';
}
```

HTML image I want clickable here is what I have tried

```
<div id="wid1"><a href="#" onclick="toggle('widget1')"><img src="widLayOut1.jpg"   
height="200" width="200" /></a></div>
```

rest of the HTML

```
<div id="widget1" style="display:none"><img src="widget1.jpg" /></div>
enter code here
```

Thoughts

Comment: I don't see an element with an ID of "widget1" in your HTML.

Comment: SorryI forgot too add that when I posted, its in there now

Comment: Why is it important that you click the image and not the link? With the link you get the pointer for free. Still remember to return false on the link like I showed you in the other very similar question you posed. Perhaps you will do us the favour and tell us what you want to achieve - perhaps you are looking in the wrong direction... Apart from the inline click handlers that are frowned upon here and the missing return false, I do not see what would be your problem with the code you posted

Comment: @mplungjan its not important I was just hoping to get it to work. I did not fully understand what was going on in your code that is why I have not adapted to it.

Comment: But I have now explained it, better?

Comment: @mplungjan You have I will have to review it again, I don't have the best absorption rate LOL, Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to add a click event to your image like any other element.  First add an id

```
<img id="yourImg" src="widLayOut1.jpg"
```

then

```
document.getElementById("yourImg").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("You clicked the image");
});
```

And of course if you want to support old browsers you have to do a bit more work

```
var img = document.getElementById("yourImg");

if (img.addEventListener)
    img.addEventListener("click", function(){
        alert("You clicked the image");
    });
else if (img.attachEvent)
    img.attachEvent("onclick", function(){
        alert("You clicked the image");
    });
 else 
     alert("What are you using?!");
```

**EDIT**

I was over thinking the above

```
document.getElementById("yourImg").onclick = function() {
    alert("You clicked the image");
};
```

should work just fine.  Thanks `mplungjan`

Comment: Why can't we be pragmatic and do `document.getElementById("yourImg").onclick=function() {}` which works in all browsers I know of since IE4 or so or perhaps it was NS3 that did not like img.onclick

Comment: @mplungjan - pragmatic is good - thank you, I updated my answer.  And +1 :)